# Как создать POJO обьект из YAML файла использую Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, pojo

По идее все просто если файл yaml называется application.yaml тогда обьект (POJO) со следующими аннотациями

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-data")
```

без проблем сетает в себя все данные из yaml файла.
Но если yaml файл называется к примеру **custom.yaml** то в обьект (POJO) значения из этого yaml не сетаются.
Пробовал использовать аннотация

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:custom.yaml")
```

но к сожалению тоже не помогло.

Может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает как ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySource` [не не предназначен для загрузки yaml-файлов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings).
Для десериализации POJO из таких файлов необходимо спользовать сторонние решения, например, библиотеку вроде [snakeyaml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml)

Comment: да про этот вариант я в курсе но думал может все таки есть возможность использовать средства спринга и красиво без лишнего кода смапить.
Ведь этот вариант выглядит не очень:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
File file = new ClassPathResource("custom.yaml").getFile();
CustomObject  result = mapper.readValue(file, CustomObject.class);